# Umbraco 5 how to get all roles and users

Tags: umbraco, umbraco5

I want to get all the membership roles in the system and all the members in the system.

I've tried using

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles();
System.Web.Security.Roles.GetUsersInRoles(roles[0]);
```

and a couple of others, but they all throw the not implemented error.

I'm using a clean VisualStudio Umbraco template of V5.1 running locally on IIS Express and SQL Express.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noted that the provider was not queried in populating the role listing from the backoffice and came to the conclusion that not only was getallroles not called, [it was never implemented.](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/31604-Umbraco-51-roleprovider-support)

Instead, the hive is queried for the list of roles.

Despite the claim that membership services was baked-in again starting with 5.1, it comes with some particularly serious limitations.

If you're committed to 5.1 and you need a custom roleprovider, then you'll need to come up with a solution that occasionally syncs roles to Umbraco.

If you don't need a custom roleprovider, then you can query the hive to pull the related content. The special urls are:

**security://profiles**

*Used to store profile data by the Hive Membership Wrapper. Profile data is additional data for any member/user that cannot be stored in the ASP.Net MembershipProvider*

**security://user-groups**

*Used to store the data for back office user groups/roles.*

**security://member-groups**

*Used to store the data for members' groups/roles.*

**security://member-types**

*Used to store the schema data for member types*

**security://membership-data**

*Used by the UmbracoMembershipProvider to store the ASP.Net MembershipProvider information*

**security://users**

*Used to query the Hive membership provider wrapper for back office users*

**security://members**

*Used to query the Hive membership provider wrapper for Umbraco members*

Finally, be aware that membership services are now abstracted. There's a completely new separate interface for Umbraco's take on membership.

Rather than using the 'baseline' .net membership provider and role provider, you use the membership service available in your current IRoutableRequestContext:

e.g. rather than using Membership.ValidateUser(), you would use _context.Application.Security.Members.Validate() which wraps the supplied MembershipProvider.

Good luck, and post any findings of your own as the community trudges through this release together.

EDIT: An example for getting a list of the member roles

```
using (var securityUow = context.Application.Hive.OpenReader<ISecurityStore>())
{
   return securityUow.Repositories.GetEntityByRelationType<UserGroup>
   (
          FixedRelationTypes.DefaultRelationType,  
          Umbraco.Framework.Security.Model.FixedHiveIds.MemberGroupVirtualRoot
   ).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

}
```

Comment: using the context to get the members data was exactly what I was looking for, I don't need a custom role provider for this particular project. Thank you for your help.

On a separate note what are the special URLs and how do you use them?

Sorry, still new to Umbraco as a whole.